# All USB devices stop working periodically (Ubuntu 18)

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

Once in a blue moon, I'll walk up to my computer (which has been on for a while without problems) and none of the USB devices (including the mouse and keyboard) work anymore. Unplugging/replugging the devices doesn't help.

I know that the computer is in an ok state otherwise: I can SSH in and everything seems normal. However, if I run `lsusb`, the only entries I see are:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Rebooting fixes the issue. What could cause this? Anything I can try short of rebooting?

Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned, rebooting fixes the issue until it happens again (which may be in several days...)

Comment: Write a simple once-a-minute `cron` job to log the USB state to a file, along with the `date` (in "journalctl format" ( see my AskUbuntu profile for the `tsjou` alias, and other hints)). Use the dates before and after USB failures with `--since=` and `--before=` options to `journalctl`. Read `man journalctl `. Look at the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with USB devices periodically not working anymore. I found a bash script that resets the USB devices, which solves the problem for me without a reboot.

```
#!/bin/bash

for port in $(lspci | grep USB | cut -d' ' -f1); do
    echo -n "0000:${port}"| sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind;
    sleep 5;
    echo -n "0000:${port}" | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind;
    sleep 5;
done
```